# How can I load related objects when reading an object from the database?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lazy-loading

I am fairly certain that this is a lazy loading issue, but after reading about lazy loading, I am still no closer to a solution. I have tried turning lazy loading on and off with no success. When I pull a Node from the database, the Parent and Children are null, even though such objects exist in the database.

I also added the 'IsReference = true' as an attempt to solve this issue.

I made the data members that are object references virtual at one point but I had serialization issues with the proxies.

DatabaseContext.cs

```
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
  public DatabaseContext() : base("DatabaseName")
  {
    Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
  }
  public DbSet<Node> Nodes { get; set; }
}
```

Node.cs

```
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
public partial class Node
{

  [DataMember]
  public long ID { get; private set; }

  [DataMember]
  public Node Parent { get; set; }

  [DataMember]
  public ICollection<Node> Children { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: this does not look like a lazy loading issue, your Children collection is not marked as virtual so should have been materialized with the node - are you sure there are related child notes in the DB?

Comment: Yes. If I load all the nodes (ie. var nodes = context.Nodes.ToList()) then all the relationships exist. If I load one node (ie. var node = context.Nodes.Find(1)) then all the relationships are null. And when I marked them as virtual it actually worked when loading one node, but again, I had serialization issues. I suppose I could try to fix those, but I would rather have a solution with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up passing the includes I wanted as parameters (you can use actual types or strings) to the method, and then I looped the includes since they return DbQuery objects and don't actually query the database. Thanks for the input @moi_meme (+1).

```
foreach (var include in includes)
{
  query = query.Include(include);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

see [Loading Related Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896272.aspx)

the simplest way is to use `.Include("Parent").Include("Children")` in your query

Comment: I have a lot of objects with a lot of relationships, doing 10 includes every time I want some objects is ridiculous. The code above was for example's sake.